# Why can we divide by zero in limits?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, fractions

Before I ask, I want to tell you that I am beginner in limits, so you may find some problems in my understanding.

Let's assume a function $f(x) = 15-2x^2$.  We want to know how the function behaves at $x=1$.  Specifically, we want to know the slope of tangent line at $x=1$.

Simply, we get a good formula for that by doing this: $$m=\frac{f(1)-f(x)}{x-1}.$$ Then we get the equation $$m=\frac{2-2x^2}{x-1}.$$

Now we have to take the limit to find the slope of the tangent line, $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac {2-2x^2}{x-1}.$$

To solve this we simplify it like this :
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac {2-2x^2}{x-1}
 =& \lim_{x\to 1}\frac {-2(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)} \\ 
 =& \lim_{x\to 1}-2(x+1) \\ 
 =& -2(1)-2 \\
 =& -4 
\end{align}

In algebra class when we had a fraction and we wanted to cancel something we always say $x \ne a$. For instance $\frac {1}{x-1}$. Here $x \ne 1$, because $x-1$ would be zero.

But here in limits I found something unbelievable: here we are dividing by zero and that's forbidden.

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac {-2(1-1)(1+1)}{(1-1)}.$$

We are just canceling zero in this fraction.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Simply put, **we don't**. These expressions are not $0$ but they approach $0$. There's a difference.

Comment: The limit is about what happens *near* $x=1$, not *at* $x=1$.  *At* $x=1$, the expression you are working with is undefined.  However, at any point *near* $x=1$, the function is perfectly well defined.

Comment: @ParasKhosla , But we plug 1 !

Comment: Yes because for $x-1$ and $x\to 1$ that's what it *approaches*.

Comment: Why we don't plug number that approach from $1$.Always $1=1$ not approaching from $1$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, what the limit is doing is finding the behavior of the fraction $$\frac{-2(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)}$$ as $x$ approaches $1$.  The actual value of the fraction at $1$ is irrelevant, and in this case undefined.  Therefore you can 'cancel' out the terms $(x-1)$ because everywhere other than $x = 1$ $$\frac{-2(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)} \quad \text{and}\quad -2(x+1)$$ are equal, and so their limit as $x$ approaches $1$ will also be equal.

Another way to think about it is that the function $$f(x) = \frac{-2(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)}$$ has a hole in the graph at $x = 1$, whereas the graph of the function $$g(x) = -2(x+1)$$ looks exactly the same except that the hole has been filled in.

Comment: i think here , you mean that we are changing the equation of the function to convert it to another function, but the two functions are equal in value, but the other function avoids division by zero , Right ????

Comment: Yes, the two functions are the same except at $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually canceling the factor $x-1$ from numerator and denominator.  This works as long as $x \ne 1$.  Keep in mind that in the limit, $x$ is approaching $1$; never actually equal to $1$.

Comment: Ok , But we at last we plug 1 in the equation !

Comment: @MohammadAlshareef : That's ONLY because after the cancellation, what remains is a function $f$ that is *continuous* at $x=1$. It is only by continuity of $f$ that you can then say that $\lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x)=f(1)$. Before you cancel, the original expression is *not* continuous at $x=1$ (it isn't even *defined* there!), so it is not allowed to plug in $x=1$.

Comment: Cancellation is forbidden , I am with you that it approach from one and not equal one, But we plug one , Specifically , We say that it approach from one then we plug one in the limit !

Comment: @MohammadAlshareef  : i think we use limits to Cancel or avoiding division by zero only. because x→1 means x approach 1 not equal 1 , so we can make some magic things like multplication or summation to the function to convert it to ( another function without divition by zero unlike the original function ) , and after that we cancel the limit because his job is finished to us , and then we put 1 to the function to get the value or the slope , i dont know if i am right or wrong but that is my brain took me to :)